# Browser inconsistency with the leaflet::addMapPane() function

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, blogdown

I have a problem integrating `leaflet` maps in my `blogdown` website whenever using the `addMapPane()` function to create different panes. The problem is that, when using Safari, everything works fine, but when using Chrome, the tiles won't show at all.

This specific example can be viewed [here](https://jplecavalier.rbind.io/en/post/20210113-pimp-your-maps/#putting-it-all-together) (Please, open it with both Safari and Chrome to appreciate the difference).

One could isolate the problem easily by knitting this very simple `Rmd` document :

````
---
title: Browsers inconsistency with tiles
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(leaflet)
leaflet(
  width = "100%"
) %>%
  addMapPane(
    name = "test",
    zIndex = 500L
  ) %>%
  addTiles(
    options = tileOptions(
      pane = "test"
    )
  )
```
````

When using Safari, the `html` page renders like below.

[image: safari_html]

This is the expected output, everything works fine. However, when opening the exact same `html` in Chrome, I see the following:

[image: chrome_html]

As one would see, the tiles are not rendering with Chrome. Since the browser seems to create the problem, I guess it could be `css` related, but I have no idea how to confirm this or (still better) fix this.

Anyone have a clue about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css to your document:

```
img.leaflet-tile {
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
```

I don't know why it is working in Safari and why not in Firefox & Chrome but it has to do with this css class, because it is not applied:

```
.leaflet-container .leaflet-overlay-pane svg, .leaflet-container .leaflet-marker-pane img, .leaflet-container .leaflet-shadow-pane img, .leaflet-container .leaflet-tile-pane img, .leaflet-container img.leaflet-image-layer {
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
```